# c++ sfml apply only when button pressed

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a probleme my character stay running when i release the LShift button

How can i reset the speed when the button is released ?

Actually i have this :

```
int speed(4);
int speedSprinte(20);

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
{
    keyCount++;
    speed=speedSprinte;
    std::cout<<speed<<std::endl;
}
```

i can add that but i think it possible to do that easier :

```
if(!sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
{
    keyCount++;
    speed=4;
    std::cout<<speed<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use SFML events and listen to `sf::Events::KeyReleased` (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php) or do it manually by storing the last state.

```
int speed(4);
int speedSprinte(20);
bool pressedLastTime{false};

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
{
    keyCount++;
    speed=speedSprinte;
    std::cout<<speed<<std::endl;
    pressedLastTime = true;
} 
else
{
    if (pressedLastTime)
    {
        speed = 4;
        pressedLastTime = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but i am not sure i understand how `speed=0;` make `speed=4;`
The `speed=0;` in `if(pressedLastTime)` is unless ?

Comment: sorry I think the second part of your question was added later... fixed my answer. You can also skip `pressedLastTime` if you don't need a single reset of `speed`